# Concatenation not working in ffmpeg for unknown reason

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

i'm trying to concatenate 2 videos in ffmpeg, using `ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/mylist.txt -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus output.webm`, in which `mylist.txt` is

```
file /path/to/file.mp4
file /path/to/file.mkv
```

and the output is

```
[concat @ 0x7b53638000] Line 1: unknown keyword 'file' /path/to/mylist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

i also tried using `"concat:file.mp4|file.mkv"` but it just replicated `file.mp4`
my question is, what is the problem here? [the method i used is verified on ffmpeg's website](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Why do you use `-c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus`? The FFmpeg wiki example uses `-c copy`.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón i prefer using these specific codecs because they are efficient compressors and  since the 2 videos are different codecs it also prevents any chance that the codecs will conflict seeing as there are 2 different codecs going into 1 file. i put more specific things into it such as ```-crf``` and ```-b:a``` but i thought those were unimportant in the post.

Comment: What did you use to create `mylist.txt`? Possibly a byte order mark (BOM) is present screwing it up, or make sure the text encoding is correct (UTF-8).

Comment: @llogan how would i go about re-encoding a txt file? i am absolutely sure my software is incapable, because for personal reasons i'm using google docs to make the txt

Comment: @llogan i'm using chromeos and android in this process

Comment: @JimmyBungalo, the FFmpeg wiki explictly says this about the concat demuxer: "All files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc.)". The same page explains the concatenation of files with different codecs. I believe that even if the problem is the BOM in the text file the concatenation will fail with your current command.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón i managed to concatenate 2 files with completely different codecs, likely due to me specifying their change in codecs. and the problem was a bom. i used vim on termux to remove it. i opened the file using `vi mylist.txt`, typed `:nobomb`, and saved and exited using `:wq`

Answer (score 1):

There is an invisible character called a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that is causing the error. Some text editors add a BOM: notably Windows Notepad and the Plain text (`.txt`) output from Google Docs.

A text file with a BOM is not currently supported by the concat demuxer in FFmpeg. One developer considers it to be "broken Microsoft bullshit": [#3718: ffmpeg does not correctly read input text file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3718).

Solution is to use a better text editor or remove the BOM before providing the text file to `ffmpeg`. Some Linux related examples can be seen in [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)