# Merge 675 video files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, merge

I divided the 90 minute video file into 8 seconds without loss. So far, no problem. I want to merge the resulting 675 mp4 files without converting them to a .ts file. When I convert it to TS file, 1 second of each track starts dull. Can you suggest a method that I can combine 675 mp4 files in batch without any problem?

My work on cropping;

```
    ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:08 -t 00:00:08 s1.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:16 -t 00:00:08 s2.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:24 -t 00:00:08 s3.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:32 -t 00:00:08 s4.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:40 -t 00:00:08 s5.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:48 -t 00:00:08 s6.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:00:56 -t 00:00:08 s7.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:01:04 -t 00:00:08 s8.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:01:12 -t 00:00:08 s9.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:00:08 s10.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -ss 00:01:28 -t 00:00:08 s11.mp4
```

Comment: Next time you need to split a video I recommend using the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment), and there are many Q/A on this site with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

1. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 's1.mp4'
   file 's2.mp4'
   file 's3.mp4'
   file 's675.mp4'
   ```
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.ts
   ```

Comment: With ffmpeg.exe ffplay.exe ffprobe.exe , the video files "s1, s2, s3" and input.txt did not react at all even though they were in the same folder.

file 's1.mp4'
file 's2.mp4'
file 's3.mp4'  

There are 3 video files in the folder and I processed only three of them in the notebook to try.

Comment: @RewossKy What does ffmpeg output in cmd/Powershell when you run `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.ts`?

Comment: nothing. Cmd screen does not turn on at all.

Comment: @RewossKy If you run plain command `ffmpeg` does it output anything in cmd? Or do you get `'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`?

Comment: https://youtu.be/uVDzEmgc6KE Thanks for your help. I recorded a video.

Comment: @RewossKy `test` is hiding the output from ffmpeg. In Explorer: go to folder "fdf", hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, in right click in blank area, click "Open command/Powershell window here" (see [video example](https://youtu.be/bgSSJQolR0E?t=19)). Then enter command `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.ts`

Comment: :( I did this but still can't figure it out. Do I have a chance to combine it as mp4 output without making a notepad list?
https://youtu.be/d1Vctf6kB_g

Comment: @RewossKy Try `.\ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.ts` as mentioned in the error. (I'm not a Windows user so I didn't test my suggestions on Windows. So far this is all Windows usage problems and not ffmpeg problems.) Also, please use a better text editor than Notepad: it adds junk to the text file as shown in [Concatenation not working in ffmpeg for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65571224/). Try [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: @RewossKy You can only concatenate MP4 **without re-encoding** with the concat demuxer. The concat demuxer requires a list. However you can [automatically generate the input list](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#Automaticallygeneratingtheinputfile).

Comment: I downloaded the new version of Ffmpeg and the problem is solved! Thank you so much.